# Using operator<< from one class in other

Tags: c++, operators

I have a class called Line, and in it defined operator<< like so:

```
    void write(ostream& os) {
        getList().setCurrentToFirst();
        for (int i = 0; i < getList().getNumberOfElements(); i++) {
            cout << getList().getDataFromCurrent() << endl;
            getList().setCurrentToNext();
        }
    }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Line& l) {
        os << l.getID() << endl;
        l.write(os);
    }
```

Line is a list with some data, that is written in a row each. Now I have another class called Network that has the same operator <<, but what it does it only needs to print out the name of the line and the first and last data from Line class using operator<<. How do I do that?

```
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Network& n) {
        os << n.line;
        return os;
    }
```

Comment: Just output the data you want to output then. If `Line`'s `operator<<` outputs different data then don't use it.

Comment: You should `return` the stream from your output operator. Without that the program is likely to crash. You compiler should have warned you about a missing `return` statement for you output operator. You may want to enable warnings while compiling (and, of course, address *all* warnings).

Comment: If you want a class to have different formats of printing itself, that is extensible, how about looking into the Visitor pattern and implementing the supported printing formats/structure that can be visited?

Comment: Speaking of compiler warnings, did you not get a warning about the unused `os` parameter in `write`?